# How do I use arrays in Django models?

Tags: python, django

I have model of ShortURL, which contains some data.

I want to collect metadata on each redirect (ip, time, etc), so I need to add ArrayField (which will contain dictionaries) of some sort. Didn't find anything such in docs, what do I do?

models.py:

```py
class ShortUrl(models.Model):
    full_url = models.URLField()
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # visits = {}
    # Field will contain many dictionaries like {'ip': '...', 'time': '...', 'meta': ...}
```

Comment: Can you add a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatthewBorish, Done. Not much to add here though, since question is about a Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Django only supports relational databases, that is why you didn't find these kind of fields to store in. There is `ArrayField` support for PostgresSQL database which I wouldn't suggest as it works with PostgresSQL only. More details on ArrayField is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

So the suggested approach is normalize the relation. You can separate metadata to different table, which will have `ForeignKey` relation to the ShortURL table.

```py
class Metadata(models.Model):
    short_url = models.ForeignKey(ShortURL, ...)
    ip = ...
    time = ...
    ...
```

So now your each of the `Array` element will be represented by a `Metadata` row.